# error while converting timestamp into bigint in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
     [G_L Account No_],
     CAST(timestamp as bigint)
from dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$G_L Entry]
where cast([timestamp] as bigint) > 2238406010
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '2238406010'.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What data Type you are using for  timestamp ?

Comment: its a hexadecimal field.

Comment: thanks sandip..its working now

Answer (score 0):

It should be work, i have tried as below:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS Timestamp) AS BIGINT) > 2238406010 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
```

Comment: please accept answer and up-vote if answer helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '2238406010'.

Remove extra bracket..

```
select [G_L Account No_],cast(timestamp as bigint)
from dbo.[Carlsberg India Pvt Ltd_$G_L Entry]
where (cast([timestamp] as bigint)) >2238406010
```